# Send column names from client to server for sorting data, but the client has camel case data but the server needs Pascal case data

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, web, backend

I have to send column names from client to server for sorting data in a data table, but the client has camel case data and the server needs Pascal case data as the database columns are in pascal case.

I can either process the data at client side before sending or do it at the back-end.

What is the best approach to tackle the situation?.